# Android | Push notifications on local network

Tags: android, http, laravel, push-notification, retrofit

I've been doing a lot of research without success on finding a solution to my (simple) problem. I'm building an application that does not requires to be connected to the internet but it does consumes a restful API from a server installed in the local network LAN.

Currently I'm dispatching a HTTP request every minute to see if there were any changes in the DB and alert the user of said changes. However this is not very efficient and it results in a poor performance / battery drain.

I've heard that push notifications can be implemented using Google cloud messaging, but that is not an option since it requires to go through google servers, in other words, internet.

I'm using Square's Retrofit framework for handling HTTP requests on Android, and PHP + Laravel on the server side.

Is there a way to send push notifications? If not, is 'long polling' a good practice in Android? Will it even work with Retrofit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side you can use an XMPP server, there are some XMPP servers such as Openfire, ejabberd and SleekXMPP. Please have a look at them.

On Android side you can use a client library e.g Smack or Xabber, the mobile library will automatically update with notifications or events using listeners.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea hot it works, but have you looked into specific packages like this one?

https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification